# Some dispute boundaries are cropped using the map's filter

Tags: javascript, maps, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I am trying to use the extended worldview for my MapBox maps.
I already have custom styles and trying to set filters to the map for various world views like US, CH, IN and JP, but when I do this it works incorrect and just cuts out the borders.

In other words, when I use setFilter for admin-0-boundary-disputed, admin-0-boundary and admin-0-boundary-bg for IN I don't see the borders, they are just cropped out.

At first I was thinking that these values have the same color as the countries backgrounds and tried to update it to red / blue / green, but the issue didn't go away.

this is the code I am using:

```
map.setFilter('admin-0-boundary-disputed', [
  "all",
  ["==", ["get", "disputed"], "true"],
  ["==", ["get", "admin_level"], 0],
  ["==", ["get", "maritime"], "false"],
  ["match", ["get", "worldview"], ["all", "IN"], true, false]
]);
map.setFilter('admin-0-boundary', [
  "all",
  ["==", ["get", "admin_level"], 0],
  ["==", ["get", "disputed"], "false"],
  ["==", ["get", "maritime"], "false"],
  ["match", ["get", "worldview"], ["all", "IN"], true, false]
]);
map.setFilter('admin-0-boundary-bg', [
  "all",
  ["==", ["get", "admin_level"], 0],
  ["==", ["get", "maritime"], "false"],
  ["match", ["get", "worldview"], ["all", "IN"], true, false]
]);
```

and these are my styles from the mapbox styles for these particular fields:

**admin-0-boundary-disputed:**

```
{
    "minzoom": 1,
    "layout": { "line-join": "round" },
    "metadata": {
    "mapbox:featureComponent": "admin-boundaries",
    "mapbox:group": "Administrative boundaries, admin"
    },
    "filter": [
    "all",
    ["==", ["get", "disputed"], "true"],
    ["==", ["get", "admin_level"], 0],
    ["==", ["get", "maritime"], "false"],
    ["match", ["get", "worldview"], ["all", "IN"], true, false]
    ],
    "type": "line",
    "source": "composite",
    "id": "admin-0-boundary-disputed",
    "paint": {
    "line-color": "hsl(102, 100%, 49%)",
    "line-width": ["interpolate", ["linear"], ["zoom"], 3, 0.95, 10, 3.8],
    "line-dasharray": [
        "step",
        ["zoom"],
        ["literal", [3.25, 3.25]],
        6,
        ["literal", [2.5, 2.5]],
        7,
        ["literal", [2, 2.25]],
        8,
        ["literal", [1.75, 2]]
    ]
    },
    "source-layer": "admin"
},
```

**admin-0-boundary-bg:**

```
{
    "minzoom": 1,
    "layout": {},
    "metadata": {
    "mapbox:featureComponent": "admin-boundaries",
    "mapbox:group": "Administrative boundaries, admin"
    },
    "filter": [
    "all",
    ["==", ["get", "admin_level"], 0],
    ["==", ["get", "maritime"], "false"],
    ["match", ["get", "worldview"], ["all", "IN"], true, false]
    ],
    "type": "line",
    "source": "composite",
    "id": "admin-0-boundary-bg",
    "paint": {
    "line-width": [
        "interpolate",
        ["linear"],
        ["zoom"],
        3,
        6.6499999999999995,
        10,
        15.2
    ],
    "line-color": [
        "interpolate",
        ["linear"],
        ["zoom"],
        0,
        "hsl(0, 0%, 51%)",
        22,
        "hsl(0, 0%, 51%)"
    ],
    "line-opacity": ["interpolate", ["linear"], ["zoom"], 3, 0, 4, 0.5],
    "line-translate": [0, 0],
    "line-blur": ["interpolate", ["linear"], ["zoom"], 3, 0, 10, 3.8]
    },
    "source-layer": "admin"
},
```

**admin-0-boundary:**

```
{
    "minzoom": 1,
    "layout": { "line-join": "round", "line-cap": "round" },
    "metadata": {
    "mapbox:featureComponent": "admin-boundaries",
    "mapbox:group": "Administrative boundaries, admin"
    },
    "filter": [
    "all",
    ["==", ["get", "admin_level"], 0],
    ["==", ["get", "disputed"], "false"],
    ["==", ["get", "maritime"], "false"],
    ["match", ["get", "worldview"], ["all", "IN"], true, false]
    ],
    "type": "line",
    "source": "composite",
    "id": "admin-0-boundary",
    "paint": {
    "line-color": "hsl(188, 98%, 49%)",
    "line-width": ["interpolate", ["linear"], ["zoom"], 3, 0.95, 10, 3.8],
    "line-dasharray": [10, 0]
    },
    "source-layer": "admin"
},
```